# Why is the Quillen model structure so painful to find?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Proving that the category of simplicial sets carries the Quillen model structure is undoubtedly difficult; the book by May and Ponto "A more concise course in algebraic topology" makes a considerable effort in giving an elementary view of this proof: section 17.5 begins with

> I [Peter May] have long believed that simpler proofs should be possible.
>   Correspondence between him and Pete Bousfield in the course of writing this book have led to several variant proofs, primarily due to Bousfield, that are simpler
>   than those to be found in the literature.

Near the end of the chapter, there is a paragraph trying to motivate this intrinsic difficulty:

> Proposition 17.5.12 means that the left adjoint T [geometric realization] creates the weak equivalences in sSet. In most other adjoint pair situations, it is the right adjoint that creates the weak equivalences. The difference is central to the relative difficulty in proving the model category axioms in sSet.

It caught my eye. I would like to have a precise explanation for this fact. Why should such a creation property be involved in the difficulty for $\mathbf{sSet}_\text{Quillen}$ to be found?

Comment: This is a soft question. Most likely, the authors are alluding to the fact that there are some fairly straightforward and usable results for "pulling back" cofibrantly generated model structures along right adjoints, but there are few such results for left adjoints. (Look up left/right-induced model structures.) But I dispute the implicit presupposition that weak homotopy equivalences of simplicial sets _have_ to be defined by geometric realisation. They can be defined independently – so one could equally well define weak homotopy equivalences of topological spaces in terms of simplicial sets.

Comment: I agree with @ZhenLin on both points. I'd guess May is referring to some classical transfer result (as described [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transferred+model+structure)). Further, the class of weak equivalences of the Kan-Quillen model structure on simplicial sets can be described intrinsically as the $\Delta$-localizer generated by the projections $\Delta_1 \times X \rightarrow X$, for any presheaf $X$ on $\Delta$.

Comment: I think it's fun to prove the structure on simplicial sets first (via the $Ex^\infty$ functor), and then use the transfer results to get the standard one on spaces.

Comment: I don't understand why so many people insist that the model structure on simplicial sets must be cotransferred from topological spaces.  Quillen's original construction starts by constructing  a model structure on simplicial sets directly, then transfers it to topological spaces, which is much easier.  And with modern tools (such as the Smith recognition theorem, for example) the model structure on simplicial sets can be constructed much more easily than it used to be.